# High CPU utilization during oracle group by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I had a doubt on oracle *group by* clause. 
Is group by a CPU intensive operation?

We have a query on a table with 32M rows and no index column which does group by on 7-8 columns and aggregates on 3 columns and inserts into another table. Occasionally we are seeing total CPU being utilized by oracle processes as 100%.

The query looks something like this:

```
insert into temp_table select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8,
 sum(col10), sum(col11), count(*) from orig_table group by col1, col2, 
 col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8 ;
```

As far as my understanding goes,
To group by we will have to sort and then group. Will this result in high CPU utilization? Also, what about the aggregates? Can they result in high CPU?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nobody can tell you that without further information - esp. a "query plan" (i.e. generated by EXPLAIN) of the used SELECT is necessary to see what actually goes on...

Comment: @Yahia the question is not about the optimal approach. I am interested to know the oracle behaviour when it comes to group by and aggregates. The approach that oracle follows. Hence the question. Theoretically what does oracle do?

Comment: That depends on several aspects like available RAM, configuration (SGA etc.), exact version (DB, OS, ASM...) and so on. Whatever the answer might be for a specific version it can change with any patch... what you ask is an "implementation detail" which noone can really answer without access to source code...

Comment: Fair enough. Does oracle speak about cpu intensive operations in the docs anywhere?

Comment: not that I know of - but then the Oracle are several thousand pages and I definitely don't know the complete docs...

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a GROUP BY use an unreasonable amount of CPU.  Run a query like this to find out what is using the CPU: `select * from v$sessmetric order by cpu desc`.

Comment: @jonearles Okay. will surely try out. Thanks for the hint. :D

Answer (score 2):

The explain plan would be interesting see, as always, and also if you query v$sql_workarea you'll see whether the group by is spilling to disk.

It is not only the number of rows that you are querying that is important, but also the number of rows which will be output and the average column widths for included columns, as this largely determines how much memory is required to perform the aggregation and therefore whether the sort will spill to disk. If it does then you might need increased PGA memory allocation, either set manually or by varying the total PGA size. Check the PGA and SGA buffer advisories to see whether they are in general well sized.

You might also fall victim to recent trends in server technology, which often feature CPU's with many relatively weak cores. Unless you are running parallel query you'll be confined to a single core.

Comment: Interesting. But  I'm really not concerned about the memory aspect of the query. What I'm interested is in the cpu utilization. Common sense tells that group by will be heavy. But does oracle talk about it anywhere in docs?

Answer (score -1):

You are using an aggregate function. If the table has 32 Million rows and you are attempting to aggregate all values in these columns, what were you expecting Oracle to do?
Sit in an Idle state?

An aggregate on this much data is going to take time!!!

The time taken for the group by clause is dependent on the number of distinct values in columns 1 to 8.
Before the group by is performed, the database would first have to retrieve all values for these columns and then order it "nicely" as you have requested, then insert it. Furthermore the query looks bad in general. Why would you do the aggregate sum on each column, only to potentially lose the value when doing the group by?
E.G if you have duplicate values in columns 1-8 the sum **may ** be calculated more than once for no reason.

Since you have provided no explain statement the simple answer is that with this much data being selected the aggregate "would certainly take a significant amount of time" the group by is dependent on your data. I'd be surprised if Oracle were NOT using this much CPU simply based on the number of rows you'd have to go through to retrieve a result from a table with 32Million records.

Without seeing the execution plan it's impossible to say what time is being spent where.